# Set Registry Value

Tags: c#, registry

Can I use the `Registry.SetValue()` method if the value does not exist in the registry yet?

Does this method creates the value, in addition to setting its content, or I have to determine if it is exist and then to use the `SetValue(...)`?

Thanks.

Comment: can you describe, what you want to Ask?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registry.setvalue.aspx) states, with my emphasis:

> Sets the specified name/value pair on the specified registry key. **If the specified key does not exist, it is created**.

I use such class for read/write registry:

```
public class RegistryEditor
{
    RegistryKey m_key;
    public RegistryEditor()
    {
        m_key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software\\Company name", true);
        m_key = m_key.CreateSubKey("Product name", RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree);
    }
    public string GetValue(string name)
    {
        return m_key.GetValue(name, "").ToString();
    }
    public void SetValue(string name, string value)
    {
        m_key.SetValue(name, value, RegistryValueKind.String);
    }
            ~RegistryEditor()
    {
        m_key.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: You should always call m_key.Close() to play safe.

Comment: @David Heffernan, Thanks.

Comment: Note that Set AND Get will fail if the user your application is running into have policies restriction access to registry. also UAC can block it.